# Universal Policy in Sails JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a policy to pass through all methods in my controllers. When call any method the policy fires up for the first time and it works great, but when call the same method for the second time there is no answer, it remains on hold for several minutes to respond.

The code of my policy is:

```
module.exports = function (req,res,next){
            //Servicio Elogger
            var wsEloggerUrl = "prueba.com";
            //Código de la aplicación en Elogger
            var application = 'EVD';
            //Código del modulo
            var modulo = req.options.controller;
            //Código del controlador
            var controller = req.options.action;            
            //Valores a ser enviados en la cabecera obtenidos en las peticiones http
            var token = '86c6e394-4b20-4aef-b8a6-50aeea75ddc9'; //req.get('x-auth-token');
            var uid = 'uid'; //req.get('x-auth-uid'); 
            var code = application+'-'+modulo+'-'+controller;//'ELG-MOD-INDEX';
            var headers={ 'x-auth-token': token, 'x-auth-uid': uid, 'x-auth-code': code };
            //Variables a ultilizar en la llamada al webservices eLogger
            var http = require('http'), options = {
                  host : wsEloggerUrl,
                  port : 80,
                  path: '/api/Check',
                  method : 'GET',
                  headers: headers
            };
            //Llamada webServices eLogger
            http.request(options,function(response){
                  console.log(req.url+'---'+controller+'---'+response.statusCode);
                  //Si el estatus de la respuesta es diferente de 200
                  if (response.statusCode!=200) {
                        return res.json({
                              'operation': false,
                              'validation': null,
                              'services': null,
                              'error': response.statusCode,
                              'data': "Error en validación del token. HTTP Code: "+response.statusCode
                        });
                  }

                  next();
            }).end();
      }
```

Comment: my tip is the problem is in the external site, it may have a timer or some other policy not to send same data multiple times or to answer similar looking requests

Comment: It seems you're right. You know some sort of problem between .NET services and sails js?. The service is made in .net.

Comment: I have no experience with .NET, sorry :/